# What are the consequences of killing a python script with SIGHUP?

Tags: python, signals

Sometimes I run many instances of a python script simultaneously. To do it anagrammatically I use `tmux` (a terminal multiplexer), and when I fill I'm done, or I when I have to fix something, then I kill the `tmux` session instead of exiting each of the (up to 100) script manually.

Killing the `tmux` session actually kills the `bash` processes which are parents of the `python` processes that were executed from them. If I understand correctly, it means a `SIGHUP` signal is sent to all of the `python` processes.

It cleans everything quite quickly - memory is freed (it seems), cpu is freed, sockets are closed and apparently ports are freed. The advantage is that it is a much quicker and simpler task than exiting each of the scripts.

My question is: are there any possible consequences to such a habit? If I don't care about the output of the script itself - may it cause any other damage, such as making the OS dirtier, heavier, etc? Is there a better practice?

Comment: Unless those scripts opens files anywhere, you should be fine. No real "damage" will come of it but just to be sure, you should have a cleanup function in the scripts listening via http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

Comment: And if they do open files? They do use the `logging` module with file handlers.

Comment: You'll end up with semi-finished writings within the files most likely. Depends on how you've opened the file and the filesystem used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SIGHUP` handler is called. If no `SIGHUP` handler is installed, then the default action as shown by the `signal(7)` man page is invoked.

To be certain that your scripts close all files, release all resources, etc., [install a `SIGHUP` handler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) that performs the appropriate actions.

Comment: So you say that without a signal handler, some of the files will not be closed? They will stay open until ... well, forever?

Comment: They will be closed, but they may not be closed in a state where they will make sense when opened.

Comment: OK, as I don't care about the output of the brutally killed scripts, that's not an issue (I will delete these anyway).